# Checking and Calling methods on delegate classes without importing the header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Currently I'm working on an iOS application in which I'm using delegates and I implemented something like:

```
@protocol Hello <NSObject>

@required
- (void)update:(NSDictionary *)data;
@end


@interface NotificationHandler : NSObject
{
    id <Hello>delegate;
}
- (void)sendData;
@end
```

When some specific notification occurs it will call the `sendData` method and it'll call the `update` method of `delegate`.

Everything is working fine. In the dictionary I need to pass specific values for some special delegates. So I'm importing the headers like:

```
#import "Special1.h"
#import "Special2.h"

- (void)sendData
{
   if([_delegate isKindOfClass:[Special1 class]])
   {
      //special class 1
      NSDictionary *dict = //initialize with parameters and values
      [(Special1 *)_delegate update:dict];
   }
   else if([_delegate isKindOfClass:[Special2 class]])
   {
      //special class 2
       NSDictionary *dict = //initialize with parameters and values
      [(Special2 *)_delegate update:dict];
   }
}
```

Here the issue is, I need to import all the special classes here. Is there anyway to do this without importing the class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using [**NSClassFromString**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) like:

```
- (void)sendData
{
   if([_delegate isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"Special1")])
   {
      //special class 1
      NSDictionary *dict = //initialize with parameters and values
      [_delegate performSelector:@selector(update:) withObject:dict];
   }
   else if([_delegate isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"Special2")])
   {
      //special class 2
      NSDictionary *dict = //initialize with parameters and values
      [_delegate performSelector:@selector(update:) withObject:dict];
   }
}
```